# Adding validation if another validation passed in laravel FormRequest

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

Is it possible to add validation if another validation passed for example I have the following validation rules

```
return [
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:30'],
    'password' => ['required', 'min:6'],
    'photo' => ['imageable'],
    'business_uuid' => ['required', 'uuid', 'exists:businesses,uuid'],
];
```

and I would like if the `business_uuid` validation passed to add validation for the phone number

```
'phone' => ['nullable', 'phone:'.$countryCode],
```

notice that I'm the country code will be brought from the business That's why I'm I'd like to add it if the validation passed

Comment: If the `business_uuid` is required so if it doesn't pass then the whole validation will fail. I'm not understanding why you don't want to just add the phone validation anyway.

Comment: I'm getting the country code from the ```$business->country```  so when I try to add the ```phone``` validation in the same rule it doesnt work cause it depends on the ```$business->country```

Comment: Where/how are you getting `$countryCode` in the Form Request i.e. please can you show the code for your whole Form Request class?